# Force people to enable Word macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to make sure that everyone who opens my Word document enables macros. I've thought of a document with the text: *"Please enable macros to view this document"*, and if macros are actually enabled I want to modify the file with the original content to make it seem normal.

Is there anyway I can do this in VBA?

Thanks in advance,
Robin

Comment: You want code to ensure that a user runs this code?

Comment: It sounds as though you are attempting to create malware.

Comment: Attempting to force the user to enable macros is, at best, highly irresponsible. Any document that does that should, quite correctly, be treated as malware. I strongly suggest that you look for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you must know that this cannot be done for experimented VBA users...

1. Your document must be of a type `.docm` (Macro - Enabled Document), of course;
2. Please, copy the next code in `ThisDocument` code module:

```
Option Explicit

Const bookMrk As String = "BlockBMrk"


Private Sub Document_Close()
    If ThisDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bookMrk) = True Then
        With ThisDocument
            .ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintPreview
            If ThisDocument.ProtectionType = -1 Then .Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, , "testPass", , True
            .Save
        End With
    Else
        If ThisDocument.ProtectionType = 2 Then ThisDocument.Unprotect "testPass"
        With Selection
            .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
            .TypeText Text:="Please re-open this file with ""Enable Macros"" selected." & vbCrLf & _
                            "Otherwise, you cannot see its content..." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                            " To be able to enable macros go File -> Options -> Trust Center -> " & _
                            "Trust Center Settings... -> Macro Settings and check 'Disable all macros with notification' and press OK."
            
            .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
            ThisDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:=bookMrk, _
            Range:=Selection.Range
        End With
        With ThisDocument
            .ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintPreview
            .Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Password:="testPass"
            .Save
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
    MacrosEnabled
End Sub

Sub MacrosEnabled()
    ThisDocument.Unprotect Password:="testPass"
    ThisDocument.Bookmarks(bookMrk).Select
    Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

2 bis. Protect (somehow) the VBA code to not be seen:

```
   a. Right click on the document Project (being in VBE);
   b. Choose 'Protection' tab;
   c. Check 'Lock project for viewing';
   d. Set a password (keep it in your mind, if need to modify something...);
   e. Confirm the password and press 'OK'
```

But you must know that it is not very complicated to break this password (for an experienced person).

3. Write something in the document (whatever you want), Save the document and close it.
4. Open it with or without Macro Enalbled and see what's happening...

Please, test the above solution and send some feedback.

Comment: Adding protection only prevents the user from editing the document, not viewing it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. It works just fine, but I have a few questions: where do I put my own code when macros are enabled, the message when macros are disabled is now unsaved, can I save it automatically using VBA? And now, the message when macros are disabled is a heading, how can I change the style to make it normal 12px black text?

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Please, try the solution and comment only after that...

Comment: @Robin: It depends on what "my own code" does mean... Usually, you should insert a standard module and place it there. If it should be an event, put it in `ThisDocument` module, too.

Comment: Like I said, nothing in your code prevents the user from viewing the document, even with macros disabled.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Did you try it?

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Do you have events enabled? Is the document `Close` event triggered? It does all the trick...

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Than you have a different result than I have

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Are you sure that you do not open it with (automate) macros enabled? Try setting the 'Macro Settings' as 'Disable all macros without notification', please.

Comment: "Do you have events enabled?" - Yes "Is the document Close event triggered?" - Yes. "Are you sure that you do not open it with (automate) macros enabled?" - Yes, all macros are disabled on the test machine.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt This should not be possible... Copy the next simple `Sub test()`
  `MsgBox "Test"`
`End Sub` and run it. Does it run?

Comment: I forgot the part regarding the text formatting... Please, insert the next line after `.TypeText  Text:=....`: `.Font.Size = 12: .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack`.

Comment: With macros disabled when I open the document I get the yellow bar below the ribbon warning me that macros are disabled and can see the entire document content below it, including the page break and bookmark that your code added.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt I cannot believe that... Word has a bad habit: If you open a document having macros disabled setting, but you choose 'Enable Macros', next times it makes some security evaluations and sometimes open it with macros enabled. Did you try running the simple test `Sub` I requested above? Does it work?

Comment: Whether or not you believe it is up to you. As a Word developer with 30 years experience I do know what I am doing.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Then, I am not able to tell you why your system behaves in that way. Is it a MAC environment? But, even experienced, did you try the simple macro I am asking about? What Word/Office version do you use?

Comment: MS365 on Win10. No you're simple message box doesn't run.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Then, I do not know why your system behaves differently. I am using that type of code from some years, on different Office versions and all the times it behaved the same, meaning that it does not allow seeing the content of the document without enabling macros. I cannot reproduce your problem... One last think crossing my mind, please, try moving the document in discussion on a different folder (where not having other used documents) and try opening it from there. Then can you share your document? I would like trying it. You can use [this](https://easyupload.io/) transfer site.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt It opened in protected view, so with macro disabled and it shows only the message it should. Please, try downloading by yourself, in a different folder, do not unblock it and try opening. Close the yellow band from its right 'x'. Does it still open in a way to see its content? Then, be sure to have 'Macro Settings' 'Disable all macros without notification'...

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt How did the downloaded document behave? Just curious...

Comment: Yes it opens in protected view. But protected view does not prevent the user from scrolling the document or changing the view to multiple pages, e.g. https://easyupload.io/czsx3c

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt The protected view was not the point! Did you try opening it pressing "Enable Editing", but **after setting  'Disable all macros without notification'**?

Comment: My comment remains valid. The OP wanted to hide the entire content of the document. The solution you proposed does not achieve that. There is a way of achieving it, but I am definitely not going to share it in a public forum. This entire question is essentially "how do I create VBA based malware?"

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt You are right! I used this code to force users filling in a form questionnaire.  Nobody tried scrolling down. Me neither... I tried deleting the answer but I receive a message telling that I cannot delete an accepted answer.